# pandas sample relative to group size

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, sample

I would like to sample rows by group from a database. But the size of each sample must be proportional to the number of rows in each group.

It concerns a list of projects implemented in different countries and over different years (these are my groups). And I would like to sample projects from the list, proportional to the total number of projects in each group.

The table below shows the count and proportion of projects implemented.

Hence for instance I want to sample 2 projects out of the 10 projects implemented in Burkina Faso in 2016.

I'm trying with the `.sample()` function and the `.groupby()` function, but I don't know how to use these two together?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df1` is DataFrame fro picture and `df` is original DataFrame use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1['Percent of Project'], 
             on=['Initial Financial Year','Area of Intervention'])
```

Then use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function and [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.sample(x['Percent of Project'].iat[0])
df = (df.groupby(['Initial Financial Year','Area of Intervention'], group_keys=False)
        .apply(f))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It gets me a Value error: Only integers accepted as `n` values. I'm not used to lambda functions...

Comment: @LBedo so it means in `Percent of Project` column is not integers? Is possible convert to integers before my solution? `df1['Percent of Project']=df1['Percent of Project'].astype(int)`?

Comment: indeed, it works well now! Thanks :-)